# With cloud servers who don't offer reassignable public IP addresses, how can I instantly have a domain name switch to a different instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, rackspace, amazon-elastic-ip

AWS offers Elastic IP Addresses, which are great for switching website domains to a new instance/stack without having to wait for DNS changes to propagate.

Some cloud service providers (e.g., Rackspace) do not offer such reassigning to their public IP addresses. In Rackspace's case, one of their Load Balancers would accomplish what I want, but the cost (starts at $38/month if need SSL) becomes much greater than AWS's Elastic IP addresses (free if assigned to a box or ~$8/month if not used).

Is there a way to reproduce the convenience of AWS's Elastic IP addresses when hosting on Rackspace without using a load balancer (e.g., via some particular server setup or use of a 3rd party)?

Comment: Possibly related - http://serverfault.com/questions/307689

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Elastic addresses are just the interface Amazon provides to its user-controllable load balancers.  You are still going to need some load balancer or proxy in the chain in order to replicate this function.  I did some Googling just now but am sorry to say I didn't turn up any free load-balancers apart from Amazon.

Comment: I suppose I was hoping for some "magic bullet". Obviously the load balancer setup is what most users will use with Rackspace, so I'll probably just go with that (or just use DNS). Thanks for taking the time to check on alternatives

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can use elastic IPs regardless of whether or not you use their ELB (elastic load balancer) service.